# I need to remove an old phone from my Google devices but there's no remove button, how do I get it back?

Tags: security, google-account

I've recently bought a new phone so I've synced it to my Google account and installed all the apps I use. I've also done a factory reset on my old phone to wipe it.

However, now when I go to `https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity` to remove the old phone from my list of devices there's no "Remove" button displayed when I expand the old phone's entry in the list.

There's a "Remove" button against the new phone and a message that the new phone might be suspicious activity with a link to secure my account. The help page - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630?p=devices&hl=en-GB&rd=1 - states that the way to get the "Remove" button is to follow the steps to "secure my account".

Now I know that there's no suspicious activity on my account so I don't need to change anything. So how can I tell Google that everything's OK and I'd quite like full access please.

Comment: This _might_ be better for [android.se] (assuming it's an Android device). That said, I wonder if the act of doing a factory reset sends a heartbeat back to Google that the phone is "clean". You _might_ need to do something stupid like re-establish your Google account on the phone, _then_ remove it from your account, before factory resetting it again.

Comment: I also wonder if it's a timing thing. How long has it been since you used the old phone? Maybe after a certain elapsed time Google doesn't assume that the phone is still live.

Comment: One more troubleshooting question: Is your phone listed in [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager)?

Comment: @Al yes the phone is listed in the device manager. I did consider the Android site but I thought that the problem was more with the website than the phone. I did also consider that I may have done the phone reset too soon.

Comment: The old phone was in use until the end of last week.

Comment: Well, https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity does say _"Devices that have been active on your account in the last 28 days, or are currently signed in."_, so presumably your old phone will drop off in a few weeks.

Comment: Though it seems that the question has been answered, it would most likely be more at home, and of more use, at AndroidEnthusiasts.SE

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos - I disagree. It's not really about the phone, but the website that supports the devices you use to log into to your account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Al E. was correct in his [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86532/i-need-to-remove-an-old-phone-from-my-google-devices-but-theres-no-remove-butto/88325#comment73676_86532)

It's now been more than 28 days since I wiped the old phone and it has now disappeared from the list.