# Google Account connected devices have no remove button/link

Tags: google-account, security

I can see a couple of iPhones in my [Recently Used    Devices](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity).

While probably not suspicious (I regularly log-in from friends    phones), I'd like to remove that device (de-authorize it).

The problem is that I can't remove them because **there's no "Remove" button** on any of those 2 devices.

- How can I remove them?
- Why is there no "Remove" option on them?

[image: My Recent Devices Dashboard showing my iPad has a "Remove" button/link while the iPhones don't]

---

Notes:

- My iPad does have a "Remove" option/button/link in contrast with the 2 iPhones that don't.
- There's [another question here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86532/i-need-to-remove-an-old-phone-from-my-google-devices-but-theres-no-remove-butto) about this issue but none of the answers cover the original question in any remote way.